# How to typeset Jean-Yves Girards "fu" and "wo"?

Tags: logic

How would I typeset Jean-Yves Girards fu and wo in TeX?
Or maybe there are some Unicodes for it?

[image]

http://girard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/logique2.0.pdf

Comment: Do you mean the Japanese scripts? There are Japanese fonts around, those are Katakana.

Comment: Ok, I got a first lead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu_%28kana%29

Comment: Unicode calls them KATAKANA LETTER HU (U+30D5) and WO (U+30F2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using the `CJKutf8.sty` package working with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand*\fu{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}\Unicode{"30}{"D5}\end{CJK}}
\newcommand*\wo{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}\Unicode{"30}{"F2}\end{CJK}}

\begin{document}
text \fu\ (fu) and \wo\ (wo)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The glyphs are KATAKANA LETTER HU (U+30D5) and WO (U+30F2).

I prepared the following file (except

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
フヲ
\end{CJK*}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

Running LaTeX, I got, on the console,

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\C70/gbsn/m/n/10/30 ?
....\kern -0.00002
....\kern 0.00002
....\glue 0.0 plus 0.96002
....\C70/gbsn/m/n/10/30 ?
```

so I modified the file to have

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
フヲ
\end{CJK*}

% this has been added after examining the result of \showoutput
\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname C70/gbsn/m/n/10/30\endcsname}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

Now the PDF file tells us the font is `gbsnu30`. With the help of the `fonttable` package, I see that the relevant characters are in slots `"D5` and `"F2` (as expected from their code points in Unicode).

OK, we have what we need.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{katakana}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{katakana}{m}{n}{ <-> gbsnu30 } {}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\fu}{\text{\usefont{U}{katakana}{m}{n}\symbol{"D5}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\wo}{\text{\usefont{U}{katakana}{m}{n}\symbol{"F2}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Et sourtout, la forme suggère de nouvelles opérations : ainsi le deux
constantes logiques $\fu$ (\emph{fu}) et $\wo$ (\emph{wo}) sont-elles 
issues de considerations morphologiques, sans le moindre substrat
sémantique. Puisque $\fu={\sim}\fu$, on obtient même une réfutation 
\emph{logique} de la logique classique.
\[
\fu,\quad \wo_{\fu\wo}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]